# git clone does not work in java

Tags: java, git

I am using jgit to clone a repository of using java code. I am able to clone to a local (windows) machine when testing, but unable to clone to a aws server.

Folder is not created in local path. I am creating the clone under `/tmp/loc/$proName`. I gave 777 to the `loc` folder, but not able to get a repo inside that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS
```

THat seems to be a [pending bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1228138) for which it was suggested:

> this is probably incomplete classpath in the script.
>
> Please try editing your `/usr/bin/jgit` script and changing the "`export JGIT_CLASSPATH`" line to the following:

```
export JGIT_CLASSPATH="$(build-classpath jgit slf4j args4j jsch commons-compress xz-java javaewah)"
```

> And see if that fixes the problem for you.

Comment: there is no jgit under /usr/bin/.

Comment: @Mary.Hansen OK, can you search for a jgit file in order to see where this is installed?

Comment: @Mary.Hansen OK: then it might be as simple as an incomplete CLASSPATH.

Comment: Thanks. So what would be the step I need to do now?

Comment: @Mary.Hansen Check the value of the environment variable CLASSPATH.

Comment: Is this system environment variable? (Computer- properties - advanced system settings-environment variables) or some other?

Comment: System or user environment variable

Answer (score 1):

In short - complete reinstall of Eclipse fixed the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS` error I was getting.

I'm on a mac, and I tried updating Eclipse and Java with a reboot as well and the problem persisted.

I just decided to reinstall Eclipse and that solved the problem. I moved my entire /Applications/Eclipse.app folder to a temp location, then downloaded and ran Eclipse again and it works fine, git integration is fine too ;-)